# How to redirect request in play framework with scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I am using play framework 2.5. In my application i want to intercept each request to check whether any user exists or not in session of that request. if user does not exists then request redirect to the login page. So, my question is how can i achieve it in my application ?

Thank You very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you check for the appropriate user

```
Redirect(routes.Application.login())
```

I won't assume anything about your authentication strategy, but he're is a simple token-based authentication strategy I use when I want to intercept the user on each request.

```
object UserAuthenticator extends Controller {

  case class UserAuthenticatedRequest[A](user: User, authToken: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)

  def userAuthenticated[A](p: BodyParser[A])(f: UserAuthenticatedRequest[A] => Result) = {
    Action(p) { implicit request =>
      request.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION).map(_.split(" ")) match {
        case Some(Array(k, v)) if k == "auth-token" => findUserByAuthToken(v).map(user => f(UserAuthenticatedRequest(user, v, request))).getOrElse(Unauthorized)
        case _ => Unauthorized
      }
    }
  }

  def userAuthenticated(f: UserAuthenticatedRequest[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    userAuthenticated(parse.anyContent)(f)
  }
```

Using the above, my controllers can do the following:

```
def myControllerMethod = userAuthenticated { request =>
  doSomethingWith(request.user)
}
```

You'll notice in my case I return `Unauthorized`, but you could easily replace that with the redirect you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much  @andyczerwonka. I got an idea based on your answer and solved my issue.

Comment: @Govardhan you should accept the answer if it helped