# Current Request/User details in Models in Scala Play! 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, playframework-2.5

I would like to have access to the current user somewhere deep in my models of my Play app, for things like setting the author, checking that the user can actually save this type, etc.

Ideally, what I would like to use is Guice's `@RequestScoped` to inject the same `UserIdentity` across my request, wherever I need it. However, as far as I can tell, the Play! Framework only supports `@Singleton` and no-scope. So either we'd get the same `UserIdentity` injected across requests or a different one for every model/util we requested. Both are no-gos for obvious reasons.

Is there some way to utilise this behaviour in Play 2.5?

**Other things I have tried**

I've tried using a combination of Play's session and cache. But the problem I have is that session is immutable, so I can't add anything to it to reuse in that same request.

I've looked at a bunch of auth frameworks but they all seem to focus on securing actions, not providing me with a current User object.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @pme I ended up sending my UserIdentity class through as an implicit val.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I thought so or Guice Assigned. I also gave it a try but got no answer yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281807/how-can-guices-requestscoped-be-done-with-play-2-6

Answer (score 0):

Check out [my answer to a question on redirecting requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797048/how-to-redirect-request-in-play-framework-with-scala/36797143#36797143), where I given an example of getting the current user in each request.

In this case the authorization key is handed out on login and the client passes it in on every request thereafter.

Comment: My issue is that I want the user data in the model, not in the controller which is what your answer seems to suggest.

Comment: Why not to pass user data as a parameter to your models?

Comment: @marcospereira The issue with that is the exact reason we use dependency injection. Every level of method would have to pass the identity down until we finally reached the method that actually wants to use it. It would also mean I have to instantiate it in the controller, which I don't necessarily want to do. Ideally, I want it to be injected when required. I may end up passing it implicitly, but I don't think that's ideal or idiomatic.

Comment: There is no magic here. If you need the current user somewhere deep in your call chain, you'll need to get it there on each request. Depending on the authentication method you're using, your strategy will change. What is irreducible is that it has to be injected somehow, so choose whatever method you prefer.