# How can Guice's @RequestScoped be done with Play 2.6

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I need the authenticated User, to access REST services.

My idea is to have an IdentityService that is RequestScoped and can be injected by all REST service clients.

The setup is like:
`Controller -> BusinessLogic -> RESTServiceClient`

So to passing the User down would involve lots of code.

As Guice's @RequestScoped is not supported (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/MEOAhdOJz5Q/-cukqS-ZBAAJ)

How can this be done with Play?

The Problem is also described here (without a solution so):

[Current Request/User details in Models in Scala Play! 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086994/current-request-user-details-in-models-in-scala-play-2-5)